# Statistical independence test, is it real?

Tags: probability

Statistical independence does not mean real independence.
In a roll of die experiment let $A=\{2,4\}$.  $P(A) = \frac{1}{3}$.
Let $B = \{2,1,3\}$.  $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$.
$P(A|B) = \frac{1}{3} = P(A)$.  $P(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{6} = (\frac{1}{2})\cdot(\frac{1}{3})$.
Even though A and B are really not independent.  Is there a real test of independence?

Comment: From the definition point of view, they are independent.  But if you observe that there is a common event to both A and B.  So B occurence has some influence on whether A could have occured or not.

Comment: How is that anymore "real" than the definition? The complement to B has the same influence on the result.

Comment: Fortunately "there is a common event to both A and B"! Note that if the intersection of A and B is empty, to tell somebody that B occurs is to give them a *huge* piece of information about whether A occurred or not. Hence, to have an empty intersection is, in a sense, *opposite* to being independent. Say, where did you get the notion that "Statistical independence does not mean real independence"?

Comment: General usage of indpendence has a different meaning, I think.  If I am indpendent of some one, it does not matter what that some one does.  The way independence has been defined here - has a special meaning.  And may be should be called 'probability independence'.  Or may be you are right.  May be, it will take some time to sink in that idea.

Comment: (Assuming the die is rolled) Whether B happens or not does not affect whether A happens or not.  Whether A happens or not does not affect whether B happens or not.  So they are really  independent

Comment: That is why it is called statistical independence, I think.  Even if you have common events in events, A and B, you can still A and B  independent (or more correctly only statistically independent).  In the general sense, you dont call things independent if they have some thing common.

Answer (score 2):

They *are* (informally) independent. If you know $B$ happened, you can make no more accurate a prediction about whether $A$ happened than if you are told nothing about $B$.  Similarly, knowing that $A$ happened will not give you a "betting edge" if you wish to bet on $B$.